# Create Material Table with specific kind of datasource

Tags: angular, angular-material

I don't know where to even begin with this and the material documentation hasn't been able to point me in the right direction. I want to find out if it's possible to create a `mat-table` using a datasource that looks like this:

```
[
{columnName: "First Name", rowsList: ["John","James","Mark"]},
{columnName: "Last Name", rowsList: ["Jones","Anderson", "Jacobs"]}
]
```

Ideally it would look like this

| First Name | Last Name |
| --- | --- |
| John | Jones |
| James | Anderson |
| Mark | Jacobs |

Comment: Please specify how you want the table rows to look.

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: Need to convert datasource into array of rows

Answer (score 0):

The key to this implementation is conversion of data

```
const DATA: { columnName: string; rowsList: string[] }[] = [
  { columnName: "First Name", rowsList: ["John", "James", "Mark"] },
  { columnName: "Last Name", rowsList: ["Jones", "Anderson", "Jacobs"] }
];

columns: string[] = DATA.map(x => x.columnName);
data: { [key: string]: string }[] = [];

DATA[0].rowsList.forEach((x, i) => {
  const element: { [key: string]: string } = {};
  DATA.forEach(x => {
    element[x.columnName] = x.rowsList[i];
  });

  this.data.push(element);
});
```

After this, mat-table is easy

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns">
    <ng-container [matColumnDef]="column">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{column}}</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[column]}} </td>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columns;"></tr>
</table>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ask5mv?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.ts)